# Is it possible to signin from task module in Teams - bot framework 4

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

composeExtensions commands are easily can prompt for signing in.
But how to do it with custom task module.

Scenario:

- I press button on some card
- It should show some form (if I am logged in), or show sign in button (if not logged in) which should launch auth flow same as on built-in fetch tasks for composeExtensions commands

But I cannot render sign in card in task module.

And if I render adaptive card, I cannot launch auth flow.
This button below just closing my task-module window.

```
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Sign In",
        "data": {
            "msteams": {
                "type": "signin",
                "value": "https://myoauth.com",
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sigincard is not supported in Task Module

Comment: I have another small question can we control labels text in composeExtension auth ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/messaging-extension-v3/search-extensions

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT "*If you want to use the web-based authentication flow with a conversational bot, you'll need to use a task module with a bot.*" says https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/authentication -- care to explain your sentence? so how do you start the authentication flow using task module then?